# How can I solve this problem with Regex?

Tags: regex

I have a block of text that contains the following types of string that need to locate and replace:

Structure

- 1 Letter: A or S
- Followed by 6 digits
- Followed by a dash ( - )
- Followed by either one or two numbers

Examples

- A123456-34
- A123456-2
- S123456-11

I am a complete noob (for the third time) to regex and having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: How an angry hacker cannot do that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression should work for you:

```
(([AS])(\d{6})-(\d{1,2}))
```

Comment: Or `(A|S)\d{6}-\d{1,2}` if not interested in groups.

Answer (score 4):

```
[AS]       # 1 Letter, A or S
[0-9]{6}   # 6 digits
-          # dash
[0-9]{1,2} # 1 or two digits
```